# Install kde applications after installation of kde plasma

Tags: arch-linux, kde

I installed kde plasma today but I only installed plasma-meta and not kde applications so now I am inside of kde but there is no terminal emulator for me to disable kde and enter into the main terminal

Comment: If this is a real hardware install, try Ctr-Alt-F2 to bring up a console login. If that doesn't work, you can get a single-user (non-GUI) login prompt from Grub.

Comment: Thanks alot it worked. Can't believe that was what I had to do

Comment: This works - and has worked - on every Linux distro I've built in the last 5+ years; probably much longer than that. This works on VMs as well, if you can send the Ctr-Alt-F2 characters to it.